# Can call SQL stored procedure directly, but not in Java application

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I've written a PL/SQL procedure that I'm attempting to call from a Java application. The problem is that when I call the procedure in sqlplus, it runs exactly as expected, but when it's run from the Java application, produces the following error:

```
SQLException Message:ORA-01453: SET TRANSACTION must be first statement of transaction
ORA-06512: at "JTRIBUNA.ASSIGN_PILOT2", line 24
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

The Java method is as follows:

```
private static boolean assignFlight() throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;
    try {
        // Prepare to call the stored procedure
        System.out.println("Assigning flights...");
        cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call assign_pilot2()}");
        cstmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem with assignFlight ");
        throw (e); // let caller handle after above output
    } finally {
        //closeCallableStatement doesn't compile
        //closeCallableStatement(cstmt);
        cstmt.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is the script to create the procedure:

```
create or replace procedure assign_pilot2  as

--cursor through flights
CURSOR fl_cur IS
    SELECT * FROM flights
    ORDER BY departs;

--createSP1
CURSOR pl_cur IS
    SELECT e.eid, ename, a.aid, cruisingrange
    FROM employees1 e
    INNER JOIN certified1 c
    ON e.eid=c.eid
    INNER JOIN aircraft a
    ON c.aid=a.aid
    ORDER BY cruisingrange ASC;

pl_row pl_cur%ROWTYPE;
fl_row fl_cur%ROWTYPE;
is_assigned number;
need_delay number;

BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    dbms_output.put_line('hi from SP assign_pilot2');
    --loop through flights
    FOR fl_row IN fl_cur LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('processing flight '|| fl_row.flno);

        --loop cursor through pilots
        FOR pl_row IN pl_cur LOOP
            --see if the range is long enough
            IF (pl_row.cruisingrange >= fl_row.distance) THEN
                --see if pilot is available (not present in flight_assignments)
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                INTO is_assigned
                FROM flight_assignments FA
                WHERE FA.eid = pl_row.eid;

                --if pilot is available
                IF(is_assigned = 0) THEN
                    --add fight to flight_assignments;
                    INSERT INTO flight_assignments
                    VALUES(fl_row.flno, pl_row.aid, pl_row.eid);
                    EXIT;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        --if flight isn't present in flight_assignments, delay it
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO need_delay
        FROM flight_assignments FA
        WHERE FA.flno = fl_row.flno;

        IF(need_delay = 0) THEN
            INSERT INTO delayed_flights
            VALUES(fl_row.flno);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
show errors;
```

The part that's really confusing me is that the error is a syntax one. As I mentioned before, I can call this procedure from sqlplus normally, and it does exactly what I want it to.

I'm new to working with transactional SQL, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What user are you connecting your Java app to your database with, is it the same user in whose schema ASSIGN_PILOT2 was created, and if not does the connecting user have an explicit EXECUTE grant on ASSIGN_PILOT2?

Comment: It's the same user, and I'm connecting with a series of prompts that put together a connection string. The whole thing is put together in this line:

    `connStr = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host + ":" + port + ":" + sid;`

I should have mentioned it earlier, but the procedure also runs as expected if I snip out the lines of code that make it a transaction.

Comment: Is it possible that some previous uncommitted transaction is causing this issue. Can you try writing a commit in your procedure just before the     SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE statement and check if the issue persists.